# when the start_time and end_time is already in mysql i cannot insert the same time and insert between them

Tags: php, sql, time

I have this table

```
   _________________________________
   |id|date      |stime   |etime   |
   |6 |2014-02-02|01:00:00|13:00:00|
   |7 |2014-02-02|14:00:00|15:00:00|
```

i keep searching right now but i guess i cant find it. so i need help.

since im new to reservation system in which the time is the only thing that matter
the system requires **the start time and the end time of the venue** in which once it is reserve.

other clients cannot reserve of the time added.

between the 1st value of the table as you have seen above.

i need guidance in this part im using **php**
this is the code that im getting a hard time:

```
   $stime = ($_POST['stime']);
 $etime = ($_POST['etime']);
 $date = date("Y-m-d");

if($stime < $etime){

$sql_all = "SELECT * FROM time";
$query_all = mysql_query($sql_all);
while($get_all = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_all)){
   echo $g_stime = $get_all['stime'];
   echo "<br>";
   echo $g_etime = $get_all['etime'];

   echo $sql_compare = "SELECT * FROM time WHERE  date='$date' BETWEEN '$g_stime' AND '$g_etime'";
   $query_compare = mysql_query($sql_compare);
   while($get_compare = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_compare)){
       $get_compare['stime'];
       $get_compare['etime'];
   }
}

 }else{
        echo 'dont insert';
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: so your row with ID **2** should be impossible?

Comment: What I could get from your explanation that you want to implement a validation which do not let insert a record with time range overlapping with  time range of any existing record. This can be implemented by checking start_time < (end_time of any existing record) AND end_time>(Start_time of the existing record). If you are planning to implement it in SQL side then you can use exists clause in where condition. let me know if you were able to solve it or not

Comment: Are you sure the date doesn't matter?

Comment: umm the date matters also i should have noticed that sorry

Comment: Glad it helped....mind giving a thumps up!!!